# Why can't I read anything but Pin 0 of PORTC?

Tags: pins, lcd, c

So I am working on this lab for my Embedded Systems class, but I can't seem to read anything but the first bit of PORTC.  What's even weirder is that if any of the pins go low the first bit will go to 0, while all the others stay at 0 no matter what.

Here is my code:

```
 /*
 * Lab_4A.c
 *
 *  Reads the value of one distance sensor
 *  and reports if light/dark to the LCD.
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 24, 2014
 *  Author: Austin R. Bartz
 *
 *  LCD Connections:
 *  E   - PB4 (Digital 12)
 *  RS  - PB5 (Digital 13)
 *  R/W - GND
 *  Data 4,5,6,7 - PD4,5,6,7 (Digital 4,5,6,7)
 *
 *  Sensor Connections:
 *  Sensor 8 - PC0 (Analog A0)
 *  Sensor 7 - PC1 (Analog A1)
 *  Sensor 6 - PC2 (Analog A2)
 *  Sensor 5 - PC3 (Analog A3)
 */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <MSOE/delay.c>
#include <MSOE/bit.c>
#include <MSOE/lcd.c>
#include <user/initPorts.c>
#include <user/readPorts.c>
#include <user/writePorts.c>

void printBinaryLCD(uint8_t);
uint8_t readSensors();

int main(void)
{
    lcd_init();
    lcd_clear();
    while(1)
    {
        uint8_t val = readSensors();
        printBinaryLCD(val);
    }
}

void printBinaryLCD(uint8_t val)
{
    lcd_home();
    uint8_t A = ((PINC & (1<<3)) == (1<<3));
    lcd_print_uint8(A);
    lcd_goto_xy(1,0);
    uint8_t B = ((PINC & (1<<2)) == (1<<2));
    lcd_print_uint8(B);
    lcd_goto_xy(2,0);
    uint8_t C = ((PINC & (1<<1)) == (1<<1));
    lcd_print_uint8(C);
    lcd_goto_xy(3,0);
    uint8_t D = ((PINC & (1<<0)) == (1<<0));
    lcd_print_uint8(D);
}

uint8_t readSensors()
{
    DDRC = 1;
    PORTC = 1;
    delay_us(10);
    DDRC = 0;
    PORTC = 0;
    delay_ms(1);
    return PINC;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of sensors did you plug to PORTC pins 0-3?

Comment: What Arduino board do you have? I guess you _can_ read the port, but your sensors are not connected properly (missing supply voltage?). As you set PC0 to output High for some time (why are you doing this?), and then back to tristate, it still may have High level when reading it.

Answer (score 2):

`DDRx` is the Data-Direction-Register-x so this can be `DDRC` or `DDRD` or anything. One register has 8 bits, 1 bit for every pin.
Making a bit 1 will result in the pin being an output. Making it 0 will result in the pin being an input.

Let's say we want to make pin 4 and 5 of port C an output.
We simply do this in the setup:

```
       //76543210  Pin numbers.
       //IIOOIIII  Input/Output indicator
DDRC = 0b00110000;//Code that actually does it.
```

So this way we can read pin 4 & 5.
But if we want to read the complete port, I suggest setting every pin of the port to input. `DDRC = 0b00000000;`

Then we can read the port as simply as `uint8_t portValueC = PORTC;`

portValueC will now have a value that represents the port's values.
It'll be binary, but you read it as decimal.
So it'll be:

```
0 for no inputs.
1 for only pin 0
2 for pin 1
3 for pin 0 & 1
4 for pin 2
5 for pin 2 & 0
6 for pin 2 & 1
```

Well. it's binary.

Let's say (pin 7,5,3,1 high)(pin 6,4,2,0 low).

This will result into the decimal value of 170.

The binary value, however, will be easier to read `0b10101010`

```
    //76543210
  //0b10101010 (Could be the value) (pin 7,5,3,1 high)(pin 6,4,2,0 low)
//^ is decimal: 170
```

You should add these macros to your project to make it easier to get single bits from this value:

```
#define bit_get(p,m) ((p) & (m))
#define bit_set(p,m) ((p) |= (m))
#define bit_clear(p,m) ((p) &= ~(m))
#define bit_flip(p,m) ((p) ^= (m))
#define bit_write(c,p,m) (c ? bit_set(p,m) : bit_clear(p,m))
#define BIT(x) (0x01 << (x))
```

This way, now you can do:

```
if(bit_get(PINC, BIT(3)))
{
 //Do only this if PORTC pin 3 is high
}
```

Read this first:

[Info on the registers](http://www.elecrom.com/2008/02/12/avr-tutorial-2-avr-input-output/)

[Info on bit fiddling](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bit-manipulation-aka-programming-101?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=37871)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your `readSensors()` function, these seem to be capacitive
sensors:

- you charge them to Vcc (`DDRC = 1; PORTC = 1;`)
- you wait until they are fully charged (`delay_us(10);`)
- you tri-state the pin (`DDRC = 0; PORTC = 0`)
- you wait for them to partially self-discharge (`delay_ms(1);`)
- you read the pin (`return PINC;`)

If my assumption is correct, and if *all* of those sensors are similar,
then here is your first bug: you are only charging the sensor on PC0. If
you want to charge the four sensors, you need to set bits 0 to 3 of the
port to active high. Thus, the first two statements in `readSensors()`
should be:

```
DDRC = 0x0f;   // bits 0 to 3...
PORTC = 0x0f;  // ...set to active high
```

Your second bug is in `printBinaryLCD()`. The function name, and the way
you call it, implies it is meant to print on the LCD the value passed as
a parameter. Instead, it is completely ignoring its parameter, and
reading `PORTC` itself. This is bad because the reading of the
capacitive sensors is time sensitive, so you should let `readSensors()`
do the work. You should then change `printBinaryLCD()` so that it
examines `val` instead of `PORTC`:

```
void printBinaryLCD(uint8_t val)
{
    lcd_home();
    uint8_t A = (val & (1<<3)) != 0;
    ...etc...
```

Comment: Nice catch on the capacitive sensors, I kinda feel the "question asker" should've mentioned that.

I also feel that ` ((PINC & (1<<1)) == (1<<1));` Is wrong.
`PINC&(1<<1)` Should evaluate to `0b1 (or 0b0)`, comparing it with `(1<<2)` `(0b100)` just doesn't make sense?

Comment: @FuaZe: Comparing to `1<<1`, although inelegant, does work. Say `PINC == 0bxxxxxxYx`, where `x` is “don’t care” and `1<<1 = 0b00000010`. Then `PINC & (1<<1) == 0b000000Y0`. It’s a “bitwise and” operation.

Comment: Yes, though my remark wasn't on the syntax.
I wanted to show that the questioners: `uint8_t C = ((PINC & (1<<1)) == (1<<1));` will not give the desired behaviour. But your code `uint8_t A = (val & (1<<3)) != 0;` did actually fix that problem.

Comment: @FuaZe: My remark isn't on the syntax either: it's on the semantics. `((x & (1<<1)) == (1<<1))` is semantically equivalent to `(x & (1<<1)) != 0`. I just prefer the `!= 0` version for a matter of style: the “do not repeat yourself” principle.

Comment: I'd say they're not equivalent. In `((x & (1<<1)) == (1<<1))` the part
`(x & (1<<1)` will evaluate to true/false (1 or 0?) and `(1<<1)` will evaluate to `0b00000010` thus they will never be equal?

Comment: @FuaZe: No. The `&` operator is a “bitwise and”, not a “logical and”: it's not just false or true, in the sense 0 or 1. Specifically, `x & (1<<1)` evaluates to either 0 or `0b00000010`. If you are not convinced, try it yourself.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's not like a logic `AND` the (1<<1) is a mask for the bit pattern of PINC which afterwards is checked again using the same mask/pattern.
I was confused as using an mask on a pattern would always cause it to be either 0 or "true" in a way it being anything bigger than 0. But yeah, you can check the outcome of it to be like the pattern itself, didn't catch that as it feels quite unlogical (and logical differs from bitwise in this case ;D).

Answer (score 0):

i can't be certain, but i reckon it has something to do with

```
DDRC = 1;
```

this equates to b000001, meaning only pinC0 is an output. i think